# Express.js application bug causes Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am working on a **[blogging application](https://github.com/Ajax30/XPressBlog)** (click the link to see the **GitHub** repo) with [Express](https://expressjs.com/), [EJS](https://ejs.co/) and MongoDB.

I am trying to introduce an *add post image* feature with Multer. Being quite new to Express, I run into trouble.

In `utils\imageupload.js` I have added:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './uploads/images')
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + '.png')
    }
});

exports.upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('postimage');
```

I import and use that in my dashboard routes file:

```
const imageUploader = require('../../utils/validation.js');

//more code

// Add Post
router.post('/post/add', imageUploader.upload, validator.addPostCheck, dashboardController.addPost);

//more code
```

In the controller I have (among others):

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {

    upload(req, res, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("There was an error uploading the image.");
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    })

    var form = {
        titleholder: req.body.title,
        excerptholder: req.body.excerpt,
        bodyholder: req.body.body
    };

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    const post = new Post();

    post.title = req.body.title;
    post.short_description = req.body.excerpt
    post.full_text = req.body.body;

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        req.flash('danger', errors.array())
        res.render('admin/addpost', {
            layout: 'admin/layout',
            website_name: 'MEAN Blog',
            page_heading: 'Dashboard',
            page_subheading: 'Add New Post',
            form: form
        });
    } else {
        post.save(function(err) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                return;
            } else {
                req.flash('success', "The post was successfully added");
                req.session.save(() => res.redirect('/dashboard'));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

As long as the line `imageUploader.upload` is in the controller, the entire application just crashes, with the error: `Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined] error`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the following line:

```
const imageUploader = require('../../utils/validation.js');
```

`validation.js` does not export `upload` which you are using here:

```
// Add Post
router.post('/post/add', imageUploader.upload, validator.addPostCheck, dashboardController.addPost);
```

Changing the import to

```
const imageUploader = require('../../utils/imageupload.js');
```

should fix the problem.

Regarding the problem in the admin dashboard-controller: Since you've already called the multer upload, you can remove it in `addPost`, `req` should now contain the uploaded file.

```
exports.addPost = (req, res, next) => {
    // removed the upload code
    var form = {
            titleholder: req.body.title,
            excerptholder: req.body.excerpt,
            bodyholder: req.body.body
    };
    ...
```

Comment: Doh, I did not see that! :)

Comment: But now I get another error: `TypeError: upload is not a function
    at exports.addPost (path\to\nodeblog\controllers\admin\dashboard.js:31:2)` (the upload **does** take place) :(

Comment: The multer module has export called `upload`. If you just want to call multer remove the braces: `const upload  = require('multer');`as you did in `imageupload.js`. Actually if you want to use the same uploader, just import `imageupload.js` here as well :)

Comment: What I want is to upload and display post images. I found `exports.upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('postimage');` (is this the line I should modify?) in some documentation. :)

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "has no export called `upload`" :) `exports.upload = multer({ storage: storage }).single('postimage')` is fine. I've edited my answer.

Comment: By the way - maybe using a framework like NestJS could help you getting a better project structure, we're really happy with it in our project.